# Ruby selenium webdriver. Can't navigate to dropdown and choose item from it

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber

Most of the solutions for this issue represenred as this

```
drowpdown = driver.find_element(:id, 'option1')
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Select::Support.new(dropdown)
option.select_by(:value, "x")
```

But in my case website that i'm testing doesn't have regular "dropdown" and "options".
what i'm facing here

```
<div class="sk-select"><input maxlength="" type="text" value="" class="sk-select__typing-input"> <!----> <span class="sk-select__value" title="Select a language">Select a language</span> <span class="sk-select__arrow"></span> <!----></div>
```

[example of html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqNoy.gif)

Before click on the dropdown section

```
<div class="sk-select"><input maxlength="" type="text" class="sk-select__typing-input"> <!----> <span class="sk-select__value" title="Select a language">Select a language</span> <span class="sk-select__arrow"></span> <!----></div>
<span class="sk-select__value" title="Select a language">Select a language</span>
```

After click on the dropdown

```
<div class="sk-select is-opened"><input maxlength="" type="text" value="" class="sk-select__typing-input"> <!----> <!----> <span class="sk-select__arrow"></span> <ul class="sk-select__list"><li class="sk-select__list-item js-list-item">Afrikaans<span class="sk-select__sub-value">The language is not listed in the National Interpreter Register</span>
<span class="sk-select__arrow"></span>
```

Comment: Instead of a _`gif`_, update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element before and after clicking on the dropdown element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to do two clicks one to get the dropdown list to appear and one to select a particular item on the dropdown list. If you are using Ruby I would suggest using the Capybara gem to drive interactions with your web site. With this the approach for making a selection would be something like

```
find('.sk-select').click
find('.sk-select__list.js-list-item', text: item_text).click
```

if you just wanted to click on say the first item you could use

```
all('.sk-select__list.js-list-item').first.click
```

`find` and `all` are methods provided by Capybara.